# validate vs validate_uniquess_of?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a difference between using

`validates :foo, uniqueness: true`

or

`validates_uniqueness_of :foo`?

I know this is a simple questions, but [Google didn't help](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&hs=LrG&channel=fs&ei=3HsdXd7qMaSOggf9h67ADw&q=validates+unique+true++vs+validates+uniqueness+of&oq=validates+unique+true++vs+validates+uniqueness+of&gs_l=psy-ab.3...36065.37679..37763...0.0..1.362.1912.4j3j2j2......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.IpcE3GZwpqU)

When and why should one be used over the other?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `validates` method is a shortcut to all the default [validators](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validator.html) that Rails provides. So, `validates :foo, uniqueness: true` would trigger `UniquenessValidator` under the hood. The source code for `validates` can be found [in the API doc here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates). As shown there, it basically triggers the validators of the options passed and raises an error in case an invalid option is passed.
[validates_uniqueness_of](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of) also triggers the `UniquenessValidator`, the same as `validates`. Its source code is

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/validations/uniqueness.rb, line 233
  def validates_uniqueness_of(*attr_names)
    validates_with UniquenessValidator, _merge_attributes(attr_names)
  end
```

The only difference is that with `validates_uniqueness_of`, we can ONLY validate the uniqueness and not pass additional options, whereas `validates` accepts multiple options. So we could have the following validations with `validates`:

```
validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true, <some other options>
```

But the same would not be possible with `validates_uniqueness_of`.

Comment: Nice answer. I'll upvote it if you don't use APIdock links. Please, use Rails' [official link](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates) instead.

Comment: Oh, I often used to wonder why some links were `api.rubyonrails`, while some others were `apidock`. I'd assumed that there may have been a website revamp or something, but that both supported the same documentation! Thanks for the info. I'll change the links @CAmador

Comment: Apidoc is an external site, nothing to do with Rails. It used to be very useful but it has been unmaintained (very outdated info) until recently. Some info [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27633). Thanks for the edit ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I was just going through that link. Thanks! Found out something new.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now. When it comes to `validates_uniqueness_of`, this wouldn't allow updates right? So I would need to specify `on: :create`? Is that normally how it will work?

Comment: @uno No no. It would allow updates. Just that you won't be able to update a field and set its value to something that already exists. For example, if there's uniqueness on name, and I have two names: "John" and "Doe", I won't be able to update "Doe" to "John". That'll raise an error. You could try playing around with uniqueness constraints on the console. That may help in clearing a few things.